# can send but cannot receive multicast packets

Tags: linux, ip, multicast

I'm trying to send multiple UDP datagrams to an embedded linux unit using multicast. The kernel version on the device is:

```
/ # uname -r
2.6.24.6
```

for testing purposes I'm using the codes found [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html) (added a couple of headers and changed the ip address to match the ip address of the unit)

The problem is that other devices in the same multicast group (windows PCs) are able to receive data while the unit is not. I read somewhere that the value of the rp_filter must be modified. I tried all options but to no avail.

I can run the unit as a server without any problem. But it simply does not receive.

Please note, `netstat -g` doesn't work.

```
/ # netstat -g
netstat: invalid option -- g
BusyBox v1.11.2 () multi-call binary

Usage: netstat [-laentuwxr]

Display networking information

Options:
        -l      Display listening server sockets
        -a      Display all sockets (default: connected)
        -e      Display other/more information
        -n      Don't resolve names
        -t      Tcp sockets
        -u      Udp sockets
        -w      Raw sockets
        -x      Unix sockets
        -r      Display routing table
```

Therefore I'm unable to check group memberships.

P.S: I ran the same program (code from the link above) on a linux PC and it worked normally. So the code is not the issue.

Comment: I managed to check /proc/net/igmp and it says eth0 is a member of E2010101 -> 226.1.1.1 which is correct. However I'm still not receiving any datagrams

Comment: You do not need netstat -g support to query group membership. If you strace netstat -gn on a box you will see that netstat is simply reading this information from /proc. Hence reading /proc/net/igmp ( and /proc/net/igmp6 for ipv6) will show you current group membership. (Note on my (x86) box group is 010000E0 for 224.0.0.1, meaning you might need to switch some byte order).

Comment: @amo-ej1: yupp I figured that out. Check my previous comment. However still cannot receive any datagrams.

Comment: Port 4321 is also open. Just checked in /proc/net/udp

Comment: been trying to get it to work for the past 2 days. According to everything I have checked so far (port, group membership ...), it should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. After messing around with everything i can find on the system, I got it to work by running eth0 in promiscuous mode

```
ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

Comment: Although I believe this is an ethernet driver bug. It should also work in promiscuous mode.

Comment: EDIT: in non-promiscuous mode*